# How do I look up a value in a table that contains RANGES OF VALUES (low and high) and return points associated with that range?

Tags: google-sheets

I have one spreadsheet that records hours of sleep for the user. I need to look up a point value associated with the hours of sleep on another sheet. Instead of listing out every possible amount of hours in 15-minute increments (0.00, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75, etc. ad infinitum), I have a table that lists ranges. For example, "Low" sleep quantity is 6.00-6.99, while "Ideal" is 7.00-8.49.

For the ranges, I use one column in the row for the Low value (such as 7.00, in the last example) and one column for the high (8.49). A column to the right then gives the amount of points that are associated with each row. (Ideal quantity = 4, Low quantity = 2, etc.)

Currently, I'm using the following formula:

```
=IFS(ISBLANK($E6),,
ISBETWEEN($DH6,'⚙️SLP SETTINGS'!$H$4,'⚙️SLP SETTINGS'!$I$4),'⚙️SLP SETTINGS'!$J$4,
ISBETWEEN($DH6,'⚙️SLP SETTINGS'!$H$5,'⚙️SLP SETTINGS'!$I$5),'⚙️SLP SETTINGS'!$J$5,
ISBETWEEN($DH6,'⚙️SLP SETTINGS'!$H$6,'⚙️SLP SETTINGS'!$I$6),'⚙️SLP SETTINGS'!$J$6,
ISBETWEEN($DH6,'⚙️SLP SETTINGS'!$H$7,'⚙️SLP SETTINGS'!$I$7),'⚙️SLP SETTINGS'!$J$7,
[ETC]
```

In the code above, Col DH holds the quantity of sleep on the main sheet, and on the Sleep Settings sheet, Col H is the Low value, Col I is the High value, and Col J holds the point value associated with the range. The formula works, but it seems ungainly. Is there a better way than using all these ISBETWEENs within an IFS?

Any help would be much appreciated.

---

Just an update: The approach suggested below works like a charm. I never understood the usefulness of "Approximate Match" on lookups. Now I do. It allows you to easily use a table of possible values using ranges instead of listing every possible value. Here's the new formula (which is at least 80% shorter than what I was trying to do with INBETWEENs):

```
=IF(ISBLANK($E6),,
XLOOKUP($DH6,'⚙️SLP SETTINGS'!$H$4:$H$10,'⚙️SLP SETTINGS'!$J$4:$J$10,,-1))
```

Comment: use LOOKUP or VLOOKUP with is_sorted=TRUE.

Comment: Your answer and approach steered me in the right direction. I think I'll use an XLOOKUP with the Match Mode set to -1. That finds either an exact match -- or the closest, smaller value. Using this, the range of Low to High is implied and there's no need for the INBETWEENs.  I've never used VLOOKUP or XLOOKUP with approximate matches, so this approach eluded me. I'll give this a try tomorrow and report back. Thanks!

Comment: XLOOKUP is also a good alternative. Any lookup function works really.